# How to pass all kind of SQL-Queries via Command Line/Batch Args[] into Java?

Tags: java, sql, db2, command-line-interface, args

I want to write a little .jar which is used as a "translator" for SQL-Queries directed to a z/OS-DB2-Database.
My goal is that the application accepts SQL-Queries as Command Line Arguments manually or via shell script/cron, next to other parameters like IP, Port, User etc.

Is there a way to leave those arguments unaffected while passing them to the jar?

Example:

```
java -jar db2sql.jar SQL=={SELECT * FROM TABLE1 TAB1, TABLE2 TAB2 WHERE TAB1.XYZ = TAB2.ZYX AND TAB2.ABC LIKE 'blabla' AND TAB1.DATE >= '01.01.2015'} IP=={192.168.0.1} User=={Santa} Password=={CLAUS}
```

(please ignore that this statement is senseless, but i hope you get the trick)

My Problem is reading out that Command Line parameters, mostly special characters like * , " ' etc.

#### Questions:

- Is there a list of all possible SQL-Parameters which must be escaped?
- Is there a special character which can be used as delimiter that will never occur in an SQL-Query?
- Is it possible to pass all kind of SQL Statments as ONE argument?
- Is it possible to leave special characters unhandled, e.g. Argument "*" = String "*", and not .classpath etc. ?

Kind Regards

Comment: I think stringEscapeUtils.escapeSql should help you with it.

Comment: "*Is there a special character that will never occur in an SQL-Query?*" - no there isn't. A SQL string literal can use any available character so a SQL Query can contain every possible character.

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The only way to cost-effectively communicate  from an Unix-Environment to a hosted System-z Database DB2 is to use a special JDBC-Driver (which we already own) or to send/receive files via FTP/SFTP from Unix/Windows to z/OS Host (which is... politically unwanted ;-) ). What I try to solve is a requirement for suppliying KPI's for a dashboard (red light, green light - value stream mapping), Several KPIs for that purpose consist of Job-Statuses, which are managed/stored/updated in diverse DB2-Tables while daily cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I wouldn't recommend what you're trying to do for several reasons, at least in a *NIX environment you could just use the standard way.

```
java -jar foo.jar -s "SELECT * FROM SOMETHING WHERE foo = 2" -u username -h hostname
```

You can use additional libraries to parse the parameters, but this way you would use `-s` to specify the SQL query, and wrap the param value in `"` to make it a single argument with automatic escape.

In your main method you can then get the full query with (simplified)

```
if(args[0].equals("-s"))
    sqlString = args[1];
```

Comment: What happen in that case when the SQL query contains " or ' for specific comparisons ( LIKE "123")? When you say you wouldn't recommend that for several reasons, what reasons do you mean?

Comment: You have to escape double quotes for the obvious reason, but not apostrophes (which you would use for `LIKE '123'`) or other characters. I'd advise against creating this yourself because a) creating your custom tool will most likely result in questionable quality (no offense) and b) I'd be extremely surprised if someone hasn't done this yet in a more elegant and reliable fashion.